# Debug doesn't work in Intellij IDEA 12

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I wanted to see why my code is run a little differently than I expected. I press the button and Debug:

```
Disconnected to the target VM, address: 127.0.0.1:64040 transport: socket
```

IDE: IntelliJ Idea 12, OS: Windows 7

```
cmd>netstat
      TCP    127.0.0.1:62522        T145:62523             ESTABLISHED
      TCP    127.0.0.1:62523        T145:62522             ESTABLISHED
      TCP    127.0.0.1:63544        T145:nfsd-status       ESTABLISHED
      TCP    127.0.0.1:65084        T145:nfsd-status       ESTABLISHED
      TCP    127.0.0.1:65086        T145:nfsd-status       ESTABLISHED
      TCP    127.0.0.1:65458        T145:nfsd-status       ESTABLISHED
cmd>ping 127.0.0.1:64040  - timeout
```

Comment: I am using IntelliJ 12.1.4 on Windows 7 with Java 7 update 25 and the debugger works fine in that situation.  Which versions of IntelliJ and Java are you using?

Comment: If you point to the code fragment which you expect to run but doesn't, then it is normal that the debugger won't stop at it.

Comment: Java 7 update 25 and IntelliJ Idea 12.1.4 I have same problem on my laptop Windows8 too .
Thanks to fge!

Comment: Did you set the breakpoint in the code? Does it show a checkmark when you start the debugger? Can you add some `println` just after the breakpoint to confirm that this code is running? Maybe there is some different version of the same class loaded from a different location in the classpath.